# Can I add new features into Java like delegate, late binding, etc?

Tags: c#, java, events, delegates, late-binding

Is there any way that I can add delegate features into Java by a library
for example I write add library that **add delegate as keyword** and handle delegate features like C#

```
delegate void SendMessageDelegate(Message message);

void SendMessage(SendMessageDelegate sendMessageDelegateReference)
{
  sendMessageDelegateReference(new Message("hello this is a sample message"));
}
void HandleSendMessage(Message message)
{
  Sender.Send(message);
}
```

In general, my question is: is there any way to add my new features such as:

- late binding
- delegates
- events like C#
- properties

by one or more libraries into Java instead of create a new compiler such as groovy or scala?

Comment: Or you could just use C#...

Comment: yes I use C# too but java is super fantastic :)

Comment: Yeah. With all the security vulnerabilities and a crapware installer, what more can you want!? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is no. Not with any reasonable amount of work.

However you can probably implement some or all of those features using the existing Java tools (or find a library that already does it).

You wouldn't be able to add a new keyword to the language - but it's amazing what you can do with creative use of annotations, generics, etc.

Google found this: https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/10/06/compiler.html

I've no idea how good it is.

Comment: so How this features can exists in new languages such as scala or groovy ? if these language can support these features so java must too !!! all runs on jvm ?!?!

Comment: They have custom compilers - the output bytecode is the same but they compile the source code differently.

Comment: If you think about it everything running on any computer goes down to machine code (assembler) in the end. The compiler turns what you write in the source files into something the CPU understands. Java just adds another step in the middle.

Comment: Is there any way to write custom compiler ? Is there any reference ?

Comment: Yes there are ways to write custom compilers. The fact that you are here asking this question makes it unlikely that you have the knowledge/experience required to do it though. Sorry to blunt but you are asking "how do I start the car engine" at the same time as wanting to enter a Formula 1 race.

Comment: yes you right , I have Bachelor in Computer engineering but I want to get information that How can I create custom compiler on jvm ? if you can please help me and give me some references thanks

Comment: Sorry, I need to get on with work - I've added a link into my post though. Google is your friend here but you won't find many "how to get started" on this sort of subject as it is pretty advanced stuff.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't just add your own keywords without writing a custom compiler.

JDK8, which is pretty usable but still in pre-reelase, has labmdas which covers delegates/events pretty well. Pre-JDK8 has a very bulky syntax for lambdas (anonymous inner classes) and JDK7 has MethodHandles which are similar to Delegates.

Properties? Scala has a much better solution to that issue than C# that doesn't require separate property/field constructs.